# php defined variables have null values

Tags: php, variables, null

I have some database information stored in config.inc.php and i'm trying to use it to access the database in a class I have, but for some reason, the variables are null. heres the code:

```
<?php

require_once 'dbinterface.php';
require_once 'config.inc.php';

class user {

    ...

    function user($id) {
        $this->db = new db($DB['host'], $DB['user'], $DB['pass'], $DB['database']);
        ...
    }
...
?>
```

and here's config.inc.php:

```
<?php

$DB['host'] = '192.168.1.107';
$DB['user'] = '****';
$DB['pass'] = '****';
$DB['database'] = 'qa';

?>
```

I'm not sure why i'm getting nulls, but here's my proof:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Exception' with message 'No database
>   selected' in
>   D:\development\PHP\qanda\dbinterface.php:18
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\development\PHP\qanda\user.class.php(17):
>   db->db(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) #1
>   D:\development\PHP\qanda\log.php(17):
>   user->user('1') #2 {main} thrown in
>   D:\development\PHP\qanda\dbinterface.php
>   on line 18

Comment: Is that all that's in config.inc.php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to declare `$DB` as `global` for this to work:

```
global $DB;

$DB['host'] = '192.168.1.107';
$DB['user'] = '****';
$DB['pass'] = '****';
$DB['database'] = 'qa';
```

And in your class definition:

```
function user($id) {
        global $DB;
        $this->db = new db($DB['host'], $DB['user'], $DB['pass'], $DB['database']);
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a [variable scoping](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) issue.  If your config.inc file is included in the global context, then this should work:

```
function user($id) {
    global $DB;
    $this->db = new db($DB['host'], $DB['user'], $DB['pass'], $DB['database']);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're including the files outside of the class's scope.  If you move the requires to inside the function, it will work as expected.

A better option would be to include it inside a constructor, loop through the `$DB` array, and assign its values to `$this->DB`, so you can access it in any function of your class.  You'll also need to modify your functions to use `$this->DB` instead of `$DB`.

```
function __construct() {
    require_once 'dbinterface.php';
    $this->DB = array();
    foreach ($DB as $key => $value) {
        $this->DB[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - either move the require or add "global $DB" at the start of the function

Comment: Also if you develop with NOTICES turned on you'd catch this kind of stuff much more easliy

Comment: require, and especially require_once are very intensive on the cpu, so if this function gets called multiple times in a given script, you tend to waste resources.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, using global variables is a bad idea. In this, case it works but it isn't optimal. The best idea is to use definitions.

```
define('DB_HOST', '192.168.1.107');
define('DB_USER', '****');
define('DB_PASS', '****');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'qa');

...

function user($id) {
    $this->db = new db(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [PHP help page on variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and in particular the "globals" keyword. It should get you what you need. Good luck!